# Error utilizando Estructuras anidadas en C como Pila (Push & Printf )

Tags: c, punteros

Estoy tratando de implementar estructuras en C de forma anidada para utilizarla como si fuera una Pila, estoy teniendo problemas, Estoy tratando de implementar solucion al siguiente enunciado y el error que me arroja

[image: Enunciado]

Primeramente la estructura que estoy utilizando y seguido de este el Metodo Push que utilizo para añadir un nuevo cantante a la Pila.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ARRSIZE 10
int contador = 0;

struct Disco{
 char titulo[30];
 int numCanciones;
};
typedef struct Disco discos;

//Esstructura Cantante
struct Cantante {
 int codigo;
 char nombre[30];
 int edad;
 int numDiscos;
 struct Disco elementos[10];
 };
 typedef struct Cantante cantante;

 //Estructura de la Pila
 struct Stack{  
  int top;
  struct Cantante* elemento[ARRSIZE];   
  };
  typedef struct Stack st;

  //Inicializar
  void inicializarPila(st *s) {
  s->top = -1;
  }

  //Compruebo si esta vacia
  int vacia(st *s){
  if (s->top == -1)
   return 1;
  else
  return 0;
  }

  //Compruebo si esta llena
  int llena(st *s){
  if (s->top == ARRSIZE - 1)
   return 1;
 else
  return 0;
 }

 //Agregar elemento a la pila
 void push(st *s, cantante* x){
 if (llena(s)) {
 printf("Pila llena");
 } else {
  s->top++;
  s->elemento[s->top] = x;
  printf("\nAgregado!");
 }
 contador++;
 }
```

El problema radica en que al querer agregar un cantante y al elegir el numero de Discos siempre al final de este la consola se pausa y termina automaticamente el programa y en que al imprimir la Pila se repiten los Cantantes ¿A que se debe esto?, enseño mi main.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 st *s = (st *)malloc(sizeof(st));
 inicializarPila(s);

 cantante *c = (cantante *)malloc(sizeof(cantante));
 struct Disco* elementos[10];


  
  int cod = 0;
  system("CLS");
                c->codigo = contador;
                
                printf("Ingrese el nombre del Cantante: ");
                scanf("%s",c->nombre);
                
                
                printf("Ingrese la edad del Cantante: ");
                scanf("%d",&c->edad);
                
                
                printf("Ingrese el numero de discos: ");
                scanf("%d",&c->numDiscos);
                
                
                for(int i= 0; i<c->numDiscos; i++){
                    
                    
                    printf("Ingrese el titulo del disco: ");
                    scanf("%s",elementos[i]->titulo);
                    
                    
                    printf("\nIngrese el numero de canciones del disco: ");
                    scanf("%d",&elementos[i]->numCanciones);
                    
                    
                }
                
                for(int i= 0; i<c->numDiscos; i++){
                    strcpy(c->elementos[i].titulo, elementos[i]->titulo);
                    c->elementos[i].numCanciones = elementos[i]->numCanciones;
                }
                
                system("CLS");
                push(s,c);
}
```

Al ingresar 2 cantantes con informacion distinta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi metodo de imprimir Pila:

```
void imprimirPila(st *s) {

printf("CONTADOR : %d\n\n",contador);
int aux = 0;
printf("Pila: ");

for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++) {
 printf("---------------------------------------");
 printf("\nCantante");
 printf("\nCodigo: %d ", s->elemento[i]->codigo);
 printf("\nNombre: %s ", s->elemento[i]->nombre);
 printf("\nEdad: %d ", s->elemento[i]->edad);
 printf("\nNumero de discos: %d \n", s->elemento[i]->numDiscos);


 printf("\n\nInformacion de los discos\n\n");

 for(int j= 0; j< s->elemento[i]->numDiscos; j++){
        
        printf("\t[CD] #%d Titulo: %s",aux,s->elemento[i]- 
        >elementos[j].titulo);
        printf("\n\t[CD] Numero de canciones: %d",s->elemento[i]- 
        >elementos[j].numCanciones);
    
        aux++;
    }

     printf("\n");
     printf("\n");
     printf("---------------------------------------");
  }
}
```

Al indicar que son mas de 2 discos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llevo un buen rato tratando de realizar mi ejercicio podrian indicarme que hago mal, lo agradeceria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creas un array para 10 punteros de tipo `Disco`:

```
struct Disco* elementos[10];
```

Y seguidamente accedes a dichos punteros:

```
scanf("%s",elementos[i]->titulo);
```

El problema aquí es que esos punteros no están inicializados, luego no apuntan a direcciones de memoria válidas.

Varios detalles aquí:

**La pila no necesitas crearla con `malloc`**

El objeto pila puedes crearlo por valor, la memoria dinámica resérvala para objetos grandes o elementos que tengas que compartir y mover de un sitio para otro:

```
st s;
inicializarPila(&s);
```

**Array innecesario**

Los discos tienes que almacenarlos en la estructura `Cantante`, que para eso tienes un array dentro de esa estructura. El array `elementos` que has creado en `main` no deberías utilizarlo para nada:

```
printf("Ingrese el numero de discos: ");
scanf("%d",&c->numDiscos);

for(int i= 0; i<c->numDiscos; i++)
{
    printf("Ingrese el titulo del disco: ");
    scanf("%s",c->elementos[i]->titulo);
    
    
    printf("\nIngrese el numero de canciones del disco: ");
    scanf("%d",c->elementos[i]->numCanciones);
}
```

Comment: Corregi lo que me dijiste, Elimine el Array innecesario, cree el objeto pila por valor., A si pude solucionar el evitar que se pegue al ingresar los datos de los discos, Pero sigue persistiendo el problema de aparecer los mismos datos de el ultimo cantante agregado para todos los objetos al imprimir la Pila, a que se debe., Pense que quizas podria ser el metodo Push() pero no encuentro fallas en el, que piensas que quizas pueda ser?

Comment: Si has hecho cambios en el código, lo que hay en la pregunta ya no sirve, luego no puedo aconsejarte. Prueba a depurar el código para ver qué contienen las variables y a cuáles estás accediendo. Si no aprendes a depurar los programas vas a sufrir mucho aprendiendo a programar

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar la repeticion de valores, se debe re asignar memoria en el Case 1:

```
c = (cantante*)malloc(sizeof(cantante));
```